# How to prove that $\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1 .z_2}$ is real

Tags: complex-numbers

If $\left|z_1\right| =\left|z_2\right|=1$ prove that $$\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2}$$ is a real number where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are  complex numbers.

Comment: Have you tried computing the imaginary part of the expression (by hand)?

Comment: Hint: Multiply by the conjugate of the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- A complex number $w$ is real iff $w=\bar{w}$.
- If $\left|z\right|=1$, then $\bar{z}=\frac{1}{z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1\cdot z_2} = \frac{(z_1+z_2)(\overline{1+z_1\cdot z_2})}{(1+z_1\cdot z_2)(\overline{1+z_1\cdot z_2})} = \frac{z_1+\bar z_1+z_2+\bar z_2}{2+z_1\cdot z_2+\overline{z_1\cdot z_2}}$$